# Where's "link object data" When creating new scenes?

Tags: mesh, objects, linked-data, data-blocks

There used to be an option when creating new scenes to link only object data and not the "object" itself, so every object in the new scene could have its own transformation values. Is there any workaround? And is there any particular reason why this feature was removed?

Answer (score 1):

The method to organize things is different with the new collection system. If you want to link object data, choose linked copy, then in your new scene right-click on the collection(s) and duplicate linked. Then uncheck the old one to hide it from this scene.